# What is this software style called?

Tags: java, swing, jsf, portlet, icefaces

It's a new app I want to build, but I would like **some ideas, tips or information etc.** 
it's a web app with icefaces which people can generate their own dynamic page using drag-n-drop from components I created.

Example: there are 3 "components" an inputBox, OutputBox and FixedText. user can use them to generate a "script" doing something like following:

1- drag a the fixedText and put property "welcome, my name is: "
2- drag the outputBox and select from a list of variables, "myName"
3- drag the the inputBox and select from an list of where to store the variable "usrName"

then there will be a "script reader" and render the previous "script" into a page with following:
welcome, my name is John, [an_input_field_to_enter_user_name] and a "save" button, when pressed, the user_name will be saved in db.

it's like to create my own swing or my own tags for jsf but less powerful. or like those websites which assist you to create your own home page

any criticizes, help, tips, ideas are welcome.

Comment: WYSIWYG - What you see is what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be called [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG), or just a GUI for building UIs.

Comment: but isn't WYSIWYG only for text edit? can user add "action" in it? like for input text

Comment: @Kossel: no, not necessarily. It just means, as Wikipedia says: _"content displayed during editing appears very similar to the final output"_. That "content" can be anything, not just text.